# Spacing issue in collectionView cell with dynamic configuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I have use collectionView for display the recipe image with dynamic cell configuration . all things are working fine but i have one issue related cell's spacing which are indicate in below screenshot.[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *) recipeCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
}

-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 2, 2);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10.0;
}
```

this my dynamic cell configuration code snippet.

Comment: Without the code of the Collection View Flow layout that should calculate the size/frame of the cells, or at least some indications on the constraints, that may be hard to tell what's wrong...

Comment: ok i will update my answer after day.